# how to divide a string, I mean convert 0123456789 into "01","12","23","34","45","56","67","78","89"

Tags: php, yii2

I want to know how to split numbers, such as we fill 0123456789 data as the processing.
I want the results to come out.
 "01","12","23","34","45","56","67","78","89" 
I found the problem is Bad Request (#400)
Unable to verify your data submission.
mycontroller

```
public function actionAbout() {
    $datas = yii::$app->request->post();
    $n = isset($datas['n']) ? $datas['n'] : NULL;
    $m = $n;


    return $this->render('about', [
                'n' => $n,
                'm' => $m,
    ]);
}
```

view

```
<form method="POST">
<div class="col-md-2">
    <?php echo Html::textInput('n', $n); ?>
</div>
<button class='btn-danger btn-md'>ตกลง &raquo;</button>
```

```
<?php
$data = $m;
$substr = null;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data) - 1; $i++) {
    $substr = substr($data, $i, 2);
    echo $substr . ", ";}?>
```

Comment: What if the number is "987651234"?

Comment: you already have the answer in your for loop. Is that not working?

Comment: Want to get a number by  form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$data = '0123456789';
$substr = null;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data) - 1; $i++) {
    $substr[]= substr($data, $i, 2);
}
var_dump($substr);
```

just a few change in your code

Comment: Want to get a number by  form.

Answer (score 0):

Use sprintf to format the number:

```
$str = "0123456789"; 

preg_match_all('/(.)/', $str, $numbers);

$numbers = $numbers[0];
array_walk($numbers, function( & $item, $key) {
    $item = sprintf("%02d", $item);
}); 
echo '<pre>' . print_r($numbers, true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Want to get a number by  form.